# Hide all unactive panels of a JuiAccordion when one is active

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, yii, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm a jquery nut who just fell off the tree.
I used Yii to create a multiform-view. Each form is independant of each other and all of them can be submitted using AJAX.

I'm using [CJuiAccordion](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiAccordion) to hold all the different forms and save screen space. But I just get the feeling that the other forms (even in collapsed panels) just get in the way. So I want to achieve that "All collapsed panels hide whenever one is active".

I get the idea of using the `activate( event, ui )` or `beforeActivate( event, ui )` to achieve this, but I have no idea of how to iterate over the accordion panels in order to use something like [slideDown](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/slideDown) in order to hide the unactive panels, and their counterparts to show all the collapsed panels again in case the active panel is collapsed.

Also, how can I register these events using Yii?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after research on how I could bind the `activate( event, ui )` or `beforeActivate( event, ui )` events using Yii... I was unsuccesful.

However, I found a workaround for pulling out a callback using htmlOptions, here's my CJuiAccordion render code:

```
$panels = array(
            "Panel a" =>
                    "content goes here",
            "Panel B" =>
                    "content goes here",
            "Panel C" =>
                    "content goes here"
        );
$cs = Yii::app()->clientScript;
    //my required jquery function is declared in this file
    $cs->registerScriptFile('js/accordion.js'); 
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAccordion', array(
        'panels'=>$panels,
        'id'=>'inventory-accordion',
        'options'=>array(
            'collapsible'=>true,
            'active'=>-1,
            'heightStyle'=>'content',
         ),
         'htmlOptions'=>array(
             'style'=>'width:100%;',
             'onclick'=>'togglePanels("inventory-accordion","h3")',
         ),
     )
);
```

Here goes the nice code, **js/accordion.js**

```
/**
 * Makes a jquery-ui-accordion hide all of its unactive panels whenver one is
 * selected and shows all the panels when the only active panel is collapsed
 */
function togglePanels(accordionId, headerSelector){
    var accordion = $("#"+accordionId);
    var accordionHeader = $("#"+accordionId+"> "+headerSelector);
    var active = accordion.accordion("option","active");

    if (active!==false) {
        //alert(active);
        accordionHeader.each(
            function(index){
                if (index!=active) $(this).slideUp('slow');
            }
        );
    } else{
        //alert("Show all the panels!");
        accordionHeader.each(
            function(){
                $(this).slideDown('slow');
            }
        );
    }       
}
```

I'm pretty sure this code is helpful and can be tweaked for Yii users of CJuiAccordion.